Member has protected visibility and is not accessible from the current context.PHP
My editor shows an error even the field is not a protected, now I wondering if model is valid column name or it just a bug in PHP debugging tools/extensions.
I am using VScode and I have this php related extensions:
-PHP by DEVSENSE
-PHP Profiler by DEVSENSE
-PHP Intelephense
I disabled PHP by DEVSENSE and the errors gone so its likely a bug in an extension?
Error message: Member has protected visibility and is not accessible from the current context.PHP(PHP1416) 

I tried to use it and I successfully display the data

ProductController.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Product;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        
    $products = Product::all();

    $products = $products->map(function ($product) {
        return [
            'id' => $product->id,
            'name' => $product->name,
            'brand' => $product->brand,
            'model' => $product->model,
            'description' => $product->description,
            'image_url' => $product->image_url,
            'price' => $product->price,
            'category_name' => $product->category->name ?? 'N/A',
            'supplier_name' => $product->supplier->name ?? 'N/A',
        ];
    });

    return response()->json($products);
    }
}


Product.php in Models
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function supplier()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Supplier::class);
    }
}


Here is how I create the table in migration
public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained('categories')->onDelete('restrict');
            $table->foreignId('supplier_id')->constrained('suppliers')->onDelete('restrict');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('brand');
            $table->string('model');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->string('image_url');
            $table->decimal('price');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE products AUTO_INCREMENT = 100000;');
    } 


Are you using vs code as editor??

Your question begins "I got an error..." which makes it sound like PHP itself is giving an error when you run the code; but your screenshot shows some editor highlighting the source code and popping up the error. Please [edit] your question to make clear what editor that is, and any configuration you think might be relevant (such as installed plugins).

@Subha I used VScode

@IMSoP thanks should I also change the title?

@Pyromagne It might help the right people spot it - for instance, I know plenty about PHP, but have never used VSCode.

If it helps: I had this same issue but mine was happening because of the variable $request->json, not $request->model. I was able to get the VSCode IDE error to go away by doing something like $array_request = $request->all(), then using $array_request['json'] instead.
(Like you, I have not noticed any issues in the PHP or MySQL and disabling PHP by DEVSENSE makes it go away.)

so it was likely an issue in the extension, thank you I will try to use that workaround in mine, I just can't stand that red error in the filename. I will update this post when i solved it.

i used this instead 'model' => $product['model'] and the error got away but still retrieve the value.

Both are workarounds to circumvent the DEVSENSE false positive error. However, both are done at the expense of code quality. I would rather write a bug report to the developer so that the error is fixed in the extension. If you absolutely have to, I would try 'model' => $product->{'model'}, which neither does fetch all the results nor does it perform a type conversion to an array.
